# Regex to match square brackets [] in a variety of 'incorrect' use cases

Tags: regex

I need to come up with a relatively complex regex to match a variety of patterns in some text that I have. The text has a finite variety of predefined markers, lets say marker1, marker2 to markerX etc which are in the text as such: `text text [marker1] text`

The square brackets can only be used to create these specific markers.

I want to write a regex to match the situations in which the square brackets have been used incorrectly - returning the match to the specific bracket.

For example, errors I'm trying to cover are as such:

`text here [incorrect_marker]` - invalid marker error

`text here [ more text here` - invalid use of square bracket

`text here ] more text here` - invalid use of square bracket

`text here [[marker1] but too many square brackets` - invalid use of double square bracket

I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: What is definition of `invalid marker` and please add your attempted regex

Comment: What exactly is your desired result? It's not quite clear to me. Would you just want to know which brackets are incorrect? For example, like [`\[marker\d+\](*SKIP)(*F)|[\[\]]`](https://regex101.com/r/GoCWn5/1)

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches `[` with a negative lookahead for `markerX` or `]` with a negative lookbehind for `markerX`.

Comment: Like [`\[(?!(?:marker1|marker2)\])|(?<!\[(?:marker1|marker2))\]`](https://regex101.com/r/KwfFSh/1)?

Comment: I love these questions. The infinite series of combinations of brackets that do not fall within a finite set. When you can code the infinite series to infinity, you'll have your regex.

Comment: @anubhava an invalid marker in this case is a marker (a word surrounded by the square brackets) which isn't part of our pre-determined list of markers.

For example, we have `marker1` to `markerX` as our predefined markers. These are written as `[marker1]` and `[markerX]` in the text. An invalid marker might be `[undefined]`.

Comment: @trincot this work nearly perfectly! Now just trying to work out how to capture all of the pattern when the marker is an invalid one, instead of just the brackets.

Comment: Your question says *"returning the match to the specific bracket."*. It looks that is not entirely what you want then.

Comment: Then maybe like this? [`\[(?!(?:marker1|marker2)\])(?:\w*\])?|(?<!\[(?:marker1|marker2))\]`](https://regex101.com/r/KwfFSh/2)

Comment: You forgot these invalid use of square brackets: `here ,,[[[][[[[],there` and the infinite list of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
\[(?!(?:marker1|marker2)\])(?:\w*\])?|(?<!\[(?:marker1|marker2))\]
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KwfFSh/2)

Explanation:

- `marker1` and `marker2` are the example markers -- extend as needed, separating them with `|`
- `\[` and `\]` are literal brackets. The closing one doesn't really need to be escaped with backslash.
- `(?:marker1|marker2)` matches a valid marker
- `(?!    )` is a negative look-ahead assertion: the pattern that is provided  within should **not** match the text that follows. So `(?!(?:marker1|marker2)\])` means that at the current position there should not be a valid marker followed by `]`.
- `(?:\w*\])?` optionally matches zero or more alphanumerical characters (or underscore) followed by `]` -- this is to make sure a wrong marker is matched completely and not only its opening bracket.
- `(?<!   )` is a negative look-behind assertion: the pattern that is provided within should not match the text that *preceded* the current position. This way a closing bracket can be matched on the condition that it was not preceded by a valid marker and preceding `[`.